# iOS Multiple Environment Issue After Upgrade to Flutter 1.17.1

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

I have been getting this error since I upgraded to Flutter 1.17.1 few days ago...I tried cleaning the project and switch back to the Legacy build system in Xcode but still getting the same issue.

My project has been using this method to handle multiple environments and it was working perfectly until I upgraded few days ago.
https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b

Help is definitely appreciated!

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ivanchau/AndroidStudioProjects/fella/build/ios/Debug-development-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist':
    1) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/ivanchau/AndroidStudioProjects/fella/ios/Runner/Firebase/development/GoogleService-Info.plist' to '/Users/ivanchau/AndroidStudioProjects/fella/build/ios/Debug-development-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
    2) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/ivanchau/AndroidStudioProjects/fella/ios/Runner/Firebase/production/GoogleService-Info.plist' to '/Users/ivanchau/AndroidStudioProjects/fella/build/ios/Debug-development-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'

    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: duplicate output file '/Users/ivanchau/AndroidStudioProjects/fella/build/ios/Debug-development-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist' on task: CopyPlistFile /Users/ivanchau/AndroidStudioProjects/fella/build/ios/Debug-development-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist /Users/ivanchau/AndroidStudioProjects/fella/ios/Runner/Firebase/production/GoogleService-Info.plist (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
```

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-CA)
    • Flutter version 1.17.1 at /Users/ivanchau/Documents/flutter
    • Framework revision f7a6a7906b (4 days ago), 2020-05-12 18:39:00 -0700
    • Engine revision 6bc433c6b6
    • Dart version 2.8.2


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/ivanchau/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/ivanchau/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro • 357DAB56-8A57-4AB3-A319-0FC1EBCA1515 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-4 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1):

In build phases (after openning your project/ Runner.xcworkspace. in Xcode) check the build phase called 'Copy bundle Resources' and remove the 2*n lines copying your GoogleService-info.plist per environment.

This supposes that you have a custom script that, depending of the flavour/ Scheme will copy the right file.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the similar method for different flavor. I can build for Android but cannot build for iOS anymore after upgrade to Flutter 1.17.1 and xcode 11.5

It says in your error that you have duplicates. Did you use the following command?

flutter run --flavor yourflavor

Comment: Yes. Something similar. Running that command gave me the same error.